# HTTPClient - Force traffic outside of VPN

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, dotnet-httpclient

I have a HTTPClient that is communicating with a device that always exists on the local network. When the machine is connected to a full tunnel VPN, this traffic is sent down the VPN (as you would expect). This means that communication with the local device stops.

Does HTTPClient have any options to force data to be sent on the physically local network, outside of the VPN?

Comment: What you describe is a VPN misconfiguration, or a deliberate rule. Address resolution and routing are handled by the OS, the VPN software, your router etc, not client applications. The VPN software modified the OS routing tables to forward everything targeted to your local network to the remote network.

Comment: You'll have to ask your VPN admin to fix the rules or create an exception. It's quite possible the company explicitly wants all non-localhost traffic to pass through its firewalls for security reasons

Comment: You need to set up your VPN with split tunneling. There is no way for HTTP to communicate over the main adapter, because the default route has been moved, so any traffic coming back in is going to get dropped by the firewall. It's theoretically possible to do this if you switch the firewall completely off, and implement your own HttpHandler to force the outbound adapter, but I wouldn't recommend it.